# Listen for new token contracts and log the contract address

Tags: token, logs, contract

I am writing a program in golang. I am using the `solana-go` RPC client. I want to listen to all events and when a new token is created I want to print the tokens contract. So far I have managed to find the `Program logs: Create` event which outputs:

```
([]string) (len=8 cap=8) {
 (string) (len=62) "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]",
 (string) (len=59) "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success",
 (string) (len=62) "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]",
 (string) (len=59) "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success",
 (string) (len=63) "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [1]",
 (string) (len=19) "Program log: Create",
 (string) (len=90) "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 5110 of 101037 compute units",
 (string) (len=90) "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL failed: Provided owner is not allowed"
}
```

but this is printing other information and not the token creation events I want to listen for. I have the following code:

```
        client, err := ws.Connect(context.Background(), rpc.MainNetBeta_WS)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        defer client.Close()

        sub, err := client.LogsSubscribe(ws.LogsSubscribeFilterAll, Finalized)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        // Receive and print transaction logs indefinitely
        for {
            // TODO: Use a switch here
            logResult, err := sub.Recv()
            if err != nil {
                spew.Dump(err, "<<<<<<<<<<")
                // log.Error().Err(err).Msg("Error receiving transaction log")
                // log.Error().Err(err).Msg("Error receiving transaction log")
                continue
            }

            // TODO Authenticate signature

            // Filter log messages to only include those with "Program log: Swap"
            for _, log := range logResult.Value.Logs {
                if strings.Contains(log, "Program log: Create") {
                    // Log the filtered log message
                    spew.Dump("Filtered Log:", logResult.Value)
                }
            }
            spew.Dump(logResult.Value.Logs)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think what I want to be doing here is getting the `logResult.Value.signature` and then using that to call `getConfirmedTransaction`. Once I get the transaction then I should be able to filter what I am looking for.

The only concern is this part:

```
sub, err := wsClient.LogsSubscribe(ws.LogsSubscribeFilterAll, Confirmed)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Fetching all logs might be very expensive and so I need to find a way to make this cheaper without relying on RPC providers.